# Sources of Nubuk (Gore-Tex lined) Leather Conditioner

Tags: gear, boots, footwear, gore-tex

I have a pair of Lowa Tibet Pro GTX (Nubuk leather and Gore-Tex Lined) and am wondering what conditioning creme I should use besides the stuff that Lowa sells as I generally like to buy from dedicated care companies such as Nikwax.

This is what I am thinking of currently purchasing to take care of my boots:

- To clean boots before water proofing - [Nikwax Footwear Cleaning Gel](http://www.nikwax.com/en-gb/products/productdetail.php?productid=85&itemid=-1&fabricid=-1)
- Waterproofing - [Nikwax Nubuk & Suede Proof](http://www.nikwax.com/en-gb/products/productdetail.php?productid=77&itemid=-1&fabricid=-1)
- Conditioning - ?????

Nikwax has the Conditioner for Leather [here](http://nikwax.com/en-gb/products/productdetail.php?productid=88) but it does not say anything about using on Nubuk leather.

**What I am looking for**:

- A Nubuk Leather Conditioner without beeswax as my boots are Gore-Tex lined

Any suggestions would be great.

Thankyou

**UPDATE**

I emailed Nikwax about their Conditioner for Leather product and got this response:

> Many thanks for your enquiry.
>   We do not have a conditioner specifically for the use on Nubuck and Suede. Our Conditioner for Leather is for the use on smooth leather and will smooth out the appearance of nubuck and suede which is why it is not recommended for that use. It will condition nubuck and suede but it will change the cosmetic appearance.

So will need advice on another brand if anyone is in on the 'know-how'

Comment: I don't think you condition Nubuk. Having used the "Cleaning Gel" in the past on my Nubuk boots, don't bother. Get a stiff brush and use a bit of elbow grease is much, much more effective

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same - its probably just gimmiky crap to make a profit

Comment: My experience was, if nothing else the brush on the lid is flimsy and simply disintegrated. So you couldn't scrub anything. It didn't appear the Gel itself made any impact.

Comment: Ill scrap the gel cleaner then. thanks for the advice. Do you find the Nubuck & Suede Proof any good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altberg [Leder-bok](http://www.altberg.co.uk/leder-gris/product/leder-bok/) is the product for you, all their bootcare stuff is designed for modern leathers and materials.